# android firebase database purpose and structure

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I´m about to start a project in which I need a DB on server, and my android device will retrieve some data, but not all of it (due to performance and privacy).

Does the firebase database allow that kind of use? 
(in all of the examples I saw, the mobile device have access to all the data stored in the DB).

Comment: You can set security policies on Firebase to restrict access, yes, or you can write your queries such that a user wouldn't be seeing anyone else's data

Comment: Hello Sebastian. You can use Firebase and in the android app you can create a model with the specifics fields that you want use in the app. And also you can apply different rules

Comment: Do you guys have some link please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link to Firebase Realtime Database Rules - https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/#section-overview, Also you can play with realtime database rule simulator (Check rules section inside your realtime database in the firebase console) to verify the security rules.[image: <code>[![enter image description here][1]][1]</code>]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you fully, you wish to load data into your app but not all the data. In this case, Firebase real-time database provides queries which gives you the ability to order data as well as limit the number of items you can load at an enpoint. For example, if you have a users node where all users are stored, you can load the last 100 users as follows

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
Query query = ref.limitToLast(100)
```

In this case, you will load the last 100 users may be into a recyclerview